# Tkinter GUI freezes when using multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, multiprocessing, freeze

**Can you explain to me how I prevent my python GUI from freezing, when executing a worker function as a separate process?**

I coded a python GUI, which on a button click, starts a process via the multiprocessing module. I decided for multiprocessing versus threading, as I like to have the option to 
start, pause, resume and terminate the process.

**Unfortunately while the worker process is running, the GUI freezes and becomes unresponsive so I can not press the 'PAUSE' button.**

The freezing problem with GUIs is reported on stackoverflow several times, but there does not seem to be a single source of this problem nor a unified solution. Therefore my question is not a duplicate.

I currently have no idea at all how to solve this freezing problem. 
My only guess for solution so far has been to use a thread-safe wrapper for Tkinter called mtTkinter, in the hope it would also help with the multiprocessing. But it did nothing.

Maybe there needs to be another layer added between GUI and worker process.

Any suggestions, hints and solutions are welcome.

Minimal code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time
import multiprocessing
import psutil


def test_function():        
    print 'Test process starting.'
    for i in range(11):
        print "Test process running, step: ", i
        time.sleep(1)
    print 'Test process finished.'


   class MainScreen(tk.Tk):

       def __init__(self):
           tk.Tk.__init__(self)
           self.title("CardZilla 0.1")
           self.resizable(0, 0)

           self.s_button = tk.Button(self, text="START", command=self.on_start)
           self.p_button = tk.Button(self, text="PAUSE", state='disabled',  command=self.on_pause)

           self.s_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
           self.p_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

       def update_all(self): #updates button states
           b_list= {self.s_button, self.p_button}
           for b in b_list:
               b.update()

       def on_start(self):
           if self.s_button["text"] == "RESUME":
               self.s_button["text"] = "START"
               self.p_button["text"] = "PAUSE"
               self.ps.resume() #resume command for process
           else:
               str = 'test arg'
               #queue = Queue()
               p = multiprocessing.Process(None, test_function)
               p.start()
               self.ps = psutil.Process(p.pid) #getting pid of process, how to move self.ps under def __init__(self): ?

               self.s_button["state"] = 'disabled'
               self.p_button["state"] = 'normal'
               self.update_all()

               p.join() #ending process

               self.s_button["state"] = 'normal'
               self.p_button["state"] = 'disabled'
               self.update_all()

       def on_pause(self):
           if self.p_button["text"] == "PAUSE":
               print 'Pause button clicked.'

               self.s_button["text"] = "RESUME"
               self.s_button["state"] = 'normal'
               self.p_button["text"] = "CANCEL"
               self.update_all()
               self.ps.suspend() #pausing command for process

           else:
               self.s_button["text"] = "START"
               self.s_button["state"] = 'normal'
               self.p_button["text"] = "PAUSE"
               self.p_button["state"] = "disabled"
               self.update_all()
               self.ps.terminate() #good to terminate via psutils versus native multiprocessing interface?


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ms = MainScreen()
    ms.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling [`p.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join) to wait for your process to exit inside the `on_start` function:

```
           p = multiprocessing.Process(None, test_function)
           p.start()
           self.ps = psutil.Process(p.pid) #getting pid of process, how to move self.ps under def __init__(self): ?

           self.s_button["state"] = 'disabled'
           self.p_button["state"] = 'normal'
           self.update_all()

           p.join() # this will block until `p` is complete
```

Doing this prevents control from returning to your event loop until the process has exited, which means until that happens and `on_start` exits, the GUI will be unresponsive. Remove the call to `join` and the GUI should be unblocked.

Now, this exposes other issues with your design, since you want to update the GUI only after the process has completed. You can do this by occasionally checking to see if the process has finished, using the [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) method. This way, the event loop is mostly unblocked, and we just briefly block it to see if the process has completed. If it has, we update the GUI buttons. If not, we schedule the checking method to run again in `0.5` seconds.

```
def check_proc(self):
   if not self.p.is_alive():
       # Process is done. Update the GUI
       self.p.join()
       self.s_button["state"] = 'normal'
       self.p_button["state"] = 'disabled'
       self.update_all()
   else:
       # Not done yet. Check again later.
       self.after(500, self.check_proc)


def on_start(self):
   if self.s_button["text"] == "RESUME":
       self.s_button["text"] = "START"
       self.p_button["text"] = "PAUSE"
       self.ps.resume() #resume command for process
   else:
       str = 'test arg'
       #queue = Queue()
       self.p = multiprocessing.Process(None, test_function)
       self.p.start()
       self.ps = psutil.Process(self.p.pid)

       self.s_button["state"] = 'disabled'
       self.p_button["state"] = 'normal'
       self.update_all()
       self.after(500, self.check_proc)  # Check to see if the process is done in 0.5 seconds

       #p.join() #ending process
```

Comment: @user2864740 Yes, I noticed that after posting. I've addressed it in an edit.

Comment: Works like a charm and advances my understanding. Yet, there is a lot of learning to do for me, like your example code makes clear to me. Mayn thanks, dano!

Comment: Won't it be a lot easier just to use `pool=multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1)` and  `pool.apply_async(func=test_function)` ?

This will not block and let the gui and test_function run as  separate processes.

Comment: @user3817518 You would still need a way to check that `test_function` had completed in the main thread, so that GUI elements could be safely updated.